# Angular2 PrimeNG Editing dirty flag

Tags: angular, primeng

I am using PrimeNG and have the table as editable, but how do I identify which rows were changed, as I don't see any kind of "ng-dirty" or other dirty flag set other than a _$visited flag which only shows that the cell was clicked on.  I want to be able to save all the table changes at once and also highlight the changed rows instead of saving as each cell is changed.  Sample column is as below:

```
<p-dataTable [value]="parts">
<p-column field="partLength" header="Part Length" [editable]="true" >
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer I was looking for in regards to getting the edited values ended up being calling the onEditComplete and onEdit events as below:

```
<p-datatable [value]="parts" [editable]="true" (onEditComplete)="cellEdit($event.data)" (onEdit)="cellDirty($event)"
```

However, I am still unable to figure out how to highlight the individual cells that have been edited.  I can get the index of the row and columns that I've changed by storing them in an array, however, how do I set the styles for a cell based on a list of these row and column indexes?  Or is there an easier way to show visually that a cell was changed?

Comment: Same problem here - how can I highlight edited cells?

Comment: @Samoth, What I ended up doing was initializing a second list of items that was stored in a variable in the component, then I would compare the cell value of the datatable to the unedited list and if different would set the css class there.  This was done in the cellEdit() function called by (onEditComplete).  Unfortunately, I have since moved companies, so I no longer have the code snippet to show exactly what I did, but that is what I did in short.

Comment: thank you! I got a similar answer here: https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=35&t=51598

Answer (score 0):

You should be using onEdit event of the datatable which returns a event object containing data and column as properties

```
 <p-dataTable [editable]="true" (onRowSelect)="rowSelected($event)">
  .....
 </p-dataTable>

 editing(event){

    if(_.findIndex(this.editedItems,event.data)){
    console.log(_.findIndex(this.editedItems,event.data);
    this.editedItems.push(event.data);
    console.log(this.editedItems);
    }
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZbxO1leMvGCgeuJjpjFJ?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

According to primeng use turbotable. Datatable is Deprecated

to catch the event on cell inline edit you can do something like:-

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="item[col.name]"  (keydown)="onEditColumnInline($event, item['id'])">
```

don't forget to put the following in  like :-

```
<td pEditableColumn="item">
```

Inside component then you can use debouncetime() or keycodes to optimize the call, so that you won't be calling the service on every keydown

Hope this helps, thanks

Answer (score -1):

It has a event (onRowSelect)="myMethod($event)" where $event is the row selected

```
<p-dataTable (onRowSelect)="myMethod($event)">...</p-dataTable>
```